# Magento 1.7.0.2 onepage checkout not showing payment methods

Tags: magento, payment, checkout

I'm having this problem with Magento onepage checkout:

I have a local environment with wamp and a test server.

Local environment is a clean installation + the template.

Test server is an installation + all templates that have been used before (I picked up from a previous developer)

Here the issue:

After implementing the new template on test, onepage checkout isn't showing any payment methods in frontend.

I have compared both installations files and I can't find the difference, but when I see the page source on the checkout page this is what I see:

Test Server (Payments aren't shown):

```
    <form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I see pagesource of my local, there's a lot more going on...

```
    <form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <dt>
            <input id="p_method_paypal_express" value="paypal_express" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="PayPal Express Checkout" onclick="payment.switchMethod('paypal_express')" class="radio" />
            <label for="p_method_paypal_express"> <!-- PayPal Logo -->
<img src="https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&amp;buttontype=ecmark&amp;locale=en_US" alt="Acceptance Mark" class="v-middle" />&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside','olcwhatispaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, ,left=0, top=0, width=400, height=350'); return false;">What is PayPal?</a>
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
</label>
    </dt>
        <dd>
        <ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_paypal_express" style="display:none;">
    <li class="form-alt">You will be redirected to the PayPal website.</li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
        <dt>
            <input id="p_method_authorizenet" value="authorizenet" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Credit Card (Authorize.net)" onclick="payment.switchMethod('authorizenet')" class="radio" />
            <label for="p_method_authorizenet">Credit Card (Authorize.net) </label>
    </dt>
        <dd>
        <ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_authorizenet" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="authorizenet_cc_type" class="required"><em>*</em>Credit Card Type</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select id="authorizenet_cc_type" name="payment[cc_type]" class="required-entry validate-cc-type-select">
                <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                                        <option value="AE">American Express</option>
                            <option value="VI">Visa</option>
                            <option value="MC">MasterCard</option>
                            <option value="DI">Discover</option>
                        </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="authorizenet_cc_number" class="required"><em>*</em>Credit Card Number</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="authorizenet_cc_number" name="payment[cc_number]" title="Credit Card Number" class="input-text validate-cc-number validate-cc-type" value="" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="authorizenet_cc_type_exp_div">
        <label for="authorizenet_expiration" class="required"><em>*</em>Expiration Date</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <div class="v-fix">
                <select id="authorizenet_expiration" name="payment[cc_exp_month]" class="month validate-cc-exp required-entry">
                                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Month</option>
                                    <option value="1">01 - January</option>
                                    <option value="2">02 - February</option>
                                    <option value="3">03 - March</option>
                                    <option value="4">04 - April</option>
                                    <option value="5">05 - May</option>
                                    <option value="6">06 - June</option>
                                    <option value="7">07 - July</option>
                                    <option value="8">08 - August</option>
                                    <option value="9">09 - September</option>
                                    <option value="10">10 - October</option>
                                    <option value="11">11 - November</option>
                                    <option value="12">12 - December</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="v-fix">
                                <select id="authorizenet_expiration_yr" name="payment[cc_exp_year]" class="year required-entry">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Year</option>
                                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    </ul>
    </dd>
    </dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
payment.init();
//]]>
</script>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Can someone PLEASE help me correct this? I have been stuck in this for the past few days and can't seem to at least get close to a solution :(

Thank you in advance for your time and sorry if the code looks messy.

Comment: Hi, Enable the "template path hints" from admin.Then you can see where that files are load from. Then you can easily find out the problem. Check google how to enable template path hints..

Comment: Check for errors in the ajax response from the previous step submit (shipping methods).

Comment: Thanks @Elavarasan for your answer, I have checked and I do not have that option on my /configuration/admin/debug only profiler.

Comment: Change config scope (drop down left side top corner ).. Or follow this link    ..http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento

Comment: @Elavarasan thank you! I enabled now I can see that payment.phtml is being called correctly but there's one other call of a file that doesn't exist in that location.

Comment: @Elavarasan I found my problem thank for your time and help!

Comment: @Marius Thank you so much too! I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it finally. It was a module that was hidden somewhere that was actually calling the payment methods. Since I change template the call was just empty and nothing was being showed since the extension was elsewhere in the installation.

Thank you guys for your help you did point me in the right direction to find this. Much appreciated.